# WiX toolset: Write registry key on upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an application that needs to know if it has been upgraded. So I thought of writing a registry key with the installer, which then could be read from the application. I tried to achieve this by adding the following component to the installer:

```
<Component Id ="Registry_IsUpgraded">
  <Condition>Installed AND UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Condition>
    <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_IsUpgraded" Root="HKLM"
                   Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\websmsExcelAddIn"
                   Name="IsUpgraded" Value="yes"
                   Type="string" />
</Component>
```

However, registry key is not written during the upgrade. In the msi log I found this line:

```
Component: Registry_IsUpgraded; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Null
```

I suppose `Action: Null` means that the component will not be installed, since `Action` for other Components that are installed during the upgrade is `Local`.

But why is this and why is my registry key not written? Is there maybe a better/easier way to tell my application that it has been upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

Installed and UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is always going to evaluate to false because during a major upgrade (indicated by UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) the new product is by definition not yet Installed.

I assume your application needs to do something on first run after each upgrade, yes?   If so,  just write the ProductCode property to the registry value and then in your application code trigger an event when it detects the value has changed.   This will simplify your installer requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the properties, thats good to know. However, the approach you proposed would not only trigger when an update has occured, but also when the user manually uninstalled and later on installed a newer version of the app, since my apps user settings (where I would store the product code to compare) are not deleted on uninstall. Putting the product code into the application wide settings also doesn't seem like a good idea, since writing to them would require admin rights (the app settings are in C:\ProgramFiles) ... Is there no way to just write a registry entry on upgrade?

Comment: Yes, just use UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE without the Installed. I think if you get to the root of why you need to know that in a sense transitioning from not installed to installed is an upgrade.  I suspect your trying to do some kind of data migration trigger event pattern.  Trigger the event and if nothing needs to be done then exit gracefully.

Comment: Unfortunately, the registry key is still not written if i set the condition to only UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE.

Comment: Are you doing a major upgrade or a minor upgrade?

Comment: I am doing a major upgrade (v0.9.3.0 to v0.9.4.0).

Comment: I think I may have gotten behind why UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is not working: Is it only set when removing products during an upgrade and not when installing the new version?https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa372380.aspx

Comment: Well, if there isn't an existing product to remove it isn't an upgrade. Right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that my comment could be disambigous. What I meant was that during an upgrade, before RemoveExistingProducts, UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is set. But when, still during the same upgrade process, the new product is installed, UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE doesn't appear to be set anymore. At least that's the way it seems to me... I've also toyed around a little with SetProperty elements - my findings regarding that seem to support my assumption.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes, UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE exists during the removal of the old product.  For the new product you should be able to detect that you are upgrading the old by looking at the Action Property you defined in the Upgrade table.

Comment: Closed as duplicate.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much for your time and help. I think I'll get it to work from here on. :)